# Решал задачу, столкнулся с вопросом

Tags: c++, строки, сравнение

Длина вводимых мною строк одинаковая, значит первые два условия не выполняются, значит узнает наибольшее число та часть кода, которая находится в цикле. Возвращает А, если условия из цикла не выполняются.

Объясните, почему это работает, и как это работает?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string max(string a, string b) {
  if (a.length() > b.length()){
    return a;
  }  
  if (a.length() < b.length()){
    return b;
  } 
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) 
      return a;
    if (a[i] < b[i])
      return b;
  }

  return a;
}


int main()
{
  string a, b, c;
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  cout << max(a, max(b, c));
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно поправить заголовок, сейчас из заголовка совершенно непонятно содержание вопроса. Вопрос тоже нужно дополнить подробностями. Попробуйте переписать в стиле "я делал то-то, хочу получить такой-то результат, столкнулся с интересной штукой..."

Comment: Что за вопрос такой: "почему это работает"? А почему это не должно работать?

Comment: @AnT Я думаю, человеку интересно _как_ оно работает. Просто немного по другому сформулирован вопрос.

Comment: "...узнает наибольшее число та часть кода, которая находится в цикле..." О каком "числе" вдруг идет речь?

Comment: Первые два if сравнение на размер строк в цикле for лексикографическое сравнение для строк можно сделать вместо цикла if (a > b) return a else return b;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так понятнее?

```
string max(string a, string b) {

    // Если a длиннее b, вернуть a
  if (a.length() > b.length()){
    return a;
  }  
    // Если b длиннее a, вернуть b
  if (a.length() < b.length()){
    return b;
  } 

  // Длины строк одинаковы
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
    // Как только два соответствующих символа строк отличаются, 
    // вернуть ту строку, у которой символ больше
    if (a[i] > b[i]) 
      return a;
    if (a[i] < b[i])
      return b;
  }
  // Если дошли сюда - строки одинаковы, так что вернуть одну из них...
  return a;
}
```

Конечно, какое-то странное упорядочение строк, но тут уж хозяин - барин...

Comment: не мой код, я просто поинтересовался))

Comment: @Harry,  Но вызываться будет std::max, а не жта функция

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Отнюдь - ведь `<algorithm>` не подключен. Да даже если бы и был подключен - у нашей `max` преимущество перед шаблонной...

Answer (score 0):

Так проще:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string max(string a, string b){
   if(a.length()>b.length) return a;
   else return b;
}

int main(){
   string a,b,c;
   cin>>a>>b>>c;
   cout<<max(a,max(b,c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: в Любом случае, пусть они и то равны, возвращает b...

Comment: Какое отношение этот код имеет к коду в вопросе? Что значит "проще", если этот код делает совсем другое?

Comment: Как цикл может узнать какая из них больше если обе строки у вас одинаковы? Цикл просто проходит и возвращает первый попавшиеся строку. в вашем случае это и есть А. Всё правильно работает, но Цикл тут лишнее. и то у вас Сама функция без проблем возвращает значение А, так как даже цикл на это не реагирует..

Comment: По условию задачи, код должен поддерживать число 10^100 символов)))

Comment: Так в вашем случае, вы сначала проверяете на условие Размера ваших строк, и пусть если они обе равного размера, переходите к циклу, где вы проверяете не на символ, а на индекс символа в ASCII, где собственно (ну на примере) буква Б больше чем буква А (1 цифра больше чем 0)..
и то если обе строки в точь одинаковы по символике (текст = текст) то возвращает строку a.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция принимает два строковых обькта и возвращает наибольший. Сначала сравнивается длина(чем больше длина, тем больше обьект, а если длины равные, то сравнивается посимвоьно пока соответствующий символ не станет больше.

Также функция не может быть вызвана, поскольку использованы все имена из пространства имен `std` строкой `using namespace std;`, а будет вызвана функция `std::max`. Не выбирайте имена, существующие в стандартной библиотеке, особенно, часто используемые...  std::string определен `operator>`, можно воспользоваться им и упростить код до такого:

```
string
max_str(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    const size_t l1 = a.length(),
        l2 = b.length();        
    if (l1 != l2) {             
        return l1 > l2 ? a : b;
    }       
    return std::max(a, b);
    // вызвалась бы эта функция, если не менять имя
}
```

Comment: Внутренний цикл странный. Если первые символы совпадают - вернется `b` без дальнейших проверок...

Comment: @Harry, вы правы,  исправил и добавил...

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать std
Для решения вашей задачи используйте функцию std::strcmp

> Compares two null-terminated byte strings lexicographically.
>
> The sign of the result is the sign of the difference between the values of the >first pair of characters (both interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the >strings being compared.
>
> The behavior is undefined if lhs or rhs are not pointers to null-terminated >strings.

Для вашей задачи вы можете получить с-style строку используя a.c_str()

```
std::string foo(std::string a, std::string b) {
    auto cmp_ret{std::strcmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str())};
    return cmp_ret >= ? a : b;
}
```

ссылка на источник
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp